# How to capture cpu time of a method in Java？

Tags: java, visualvm

I am trying to capture the cpu time of a method rather than running time.
I know I can use

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

to capture the system time. I found something here http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking
So I use its method. The following is the class I wrote to get the cpu time, system time,user time.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class Profile {
  public Profile(){}
  /** Get CPU time in nanoseconds. 
   * @return long*/  
  public static long getCpuTime( ) {
      ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
      return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( )?bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( ) : 0L;
  }

  /** Get user time in nanoseconds. 
   * @return long*/
  public static long getUserTime( ) {
      ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
      return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( ) ?
          bean.getCurrentThreadUserTime( ) : 0L;
      }

  /** Get system time in nanoseconds. 
   * @return long*/
  public static long getSystemTime( ) {
      ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
      return bean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported( ) ?
          (bean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime( ) - bean.getCurrentThreadUserTime( )) : 0L;
  }
}
```

Then I use the following to capture the cpu time.

```
long startTime = Profiler.getCputTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = Profiler.getCputTime();
long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

However, the duration is zero. I know in the that web page, it did explains
http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/03/java_tip_how_get_cpu_and_user_time_benchmarking#AppendixTimesandlackofnanosecondaccuracy
Time accuracies are typically no better than several thousand nanoseconds. More often they are a few milliseconds.

So is there anyway else to capture the CPU time? ( I cannot use the method to run methodToTime() hundreds times until the CPU time can be captured.)

Now I am using VisualVM to capture the time. Does anyone know if VisualVM is capturing the cpu time or the system time? Because the value I got is close to the system time I captured by using System.nanoTime().
Or can anyone suggest a profiler which can captured the cpu time of a method and can capture the cpu time of each calling of the method separately.(I notice VisualVM can only capture a total time and invocations).

Thank you.

Comment: How long does the method take if you use `System.nanoTime`? Is it likely to have a significant IO component? And why can't you run it multiple times?